# ¿Como restar los resultados de una consulta en SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT ID,PLACA,SUM(GALONES) AS GALONES,SUM(MONTO) as MONTO,MONTH(FECHA1) MES,YEAR(FECHA2) AÑO
FROM [db_stransportacion].[dbo].[v_combustible_Asignado] c
INNER JOIN [db_stransportacion].[dbo].[t_Vehiculo] v ON c.ID=v.veh_id
WHERE MONTH(FECHA1) between 6 and 12 and c.ID=10 
  and YEAR(FECHA2)=2015
GROUP BY MONTH(FECHA1),YEAR(FECHA2),ID,PLACA
```

Que me retorna la siguiente información:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Como podria agregar en la consulta la diferencia del Monto?**

Es decir restar 12,400-6,099-8,974-10,900?

Comment: ¿Siempre se cumplirá la lógica de que  coges el monto  de menor fecha y le restas los demás montos?

Comment: ¿Caul es el resultado que queres tener en esa columna? Por ejemplo para el primer registro cual seria?

Comment: @HectorScesa La consulta consiste: Los montos estan agrupados en los distintos meses segun el rango que se consulte y se desea sacar la diferencia entre el rango de fecha. Ahora mismo vienen sumados por meses y luego sacar la diferencia entre los meses.

Comment: @HectorScesa Por ejemplo: en el mes 7 hubo un monto total de 12,400 y asi sucesivamente, deseo restar el total del monto

Comment: Y es factible que almacenes en una variable el resultado *MONTO*  del mes 6 y luego en otra variable la del mes 7 y así hasta el 12, una vez obtenido estas variables restarlas?

Comment: Estoy pensando como hacerlo en stored procedure, que harias para almacenarlo? @JorgeLuisAlcantara

Comment: Con un  `declare @@montoMes6 As decimal;´ y luego ´select @@montoMes6 =  *tu consulta que obtenga el valor del mes 6* ´ puse dos arrobas por las validaciones de SO.

Comment: sabes que lo hice pero deberia contemplar cuando el monto de x mes es mas grande que el otro por que la resta no saldra bien @JorgeLuisAlcantara

Comment: Podrías hacerlo con una función, dime la lógica que te dije va por buen camino? se me ocurre una respuesta pero no quisiera irme por la tangente respondiendo algo que no te servirá

Comment: @JorgeLuisAlcantara lo hice pero sucede que estoy restando todo almacenado en cada variable de montoMes ejemplo: @@resultado=@@montoMes1-@@montoMes2,...@@montoMes12. pero la resta no sale bien, ya que hay numeros que son mayores que otro y cuando resta, se suma al quedar negativo.

Comment: Claro para ello tienes que validar tu resultado mediante una función a la cual se le debe pasar dos o mas parámetros, y si es positivo retornar el valor obtenido, en caso de ser negativo ya decides tu si va a ser cero u otro valor.

Comment: Lo que quieres es una suma/resta acumulada por mes? Es decir, tomando tu ejemplo, el mes 10 debería informar 12400-6099-8974-10900? Puedes indicar que motor de base de datos estas usando?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

El tuyo pareciera ser un problema de suma acumulada o más bien de resta acumulada. Hay varias formas de resolverlo, te sugiero que busques `cumulative sum + sql server` en el sitio en inglés, verás muchas otras alternativas. La que te propongo es relativamente sencilla de implementar, la idea es generar un numerador por fila y por grupo usando `ROW_NUMBER()` para luego aprovecharlo mediante un `JOIN` para que por ejemplo en la fila #3 sume el valor del monto de la fila #1 y reste el de las filas #2 y #3.

En primer lugar, voy a armar un ejemplo, voy a crear una sola tabla para hacerlo sencillo,  en tu caso tienes dos, no debiera ser complicado adaptar lo que te propongo.

```
CREATE TABLE TablaTest (
  ID INT,
  PLACA VARCHAR(15),
  GALONES INT,
  MONTO INT,
  FECHA1 DATETIME,
  FECHA2 DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO TablaTest(ID, PLACA, GALONES, MONTO, FECHA1, FECHA2)
SELECT 10, 'EG00616', 56, 12400, '20150701', '20150701' UNION
SELECT 10, 'EG00616', 35, 6099, '20150801', '20150801' UNION
SELECT 10, 'EG00616', 5556, 8974, '20150901', '20150901' UNION
SELECT 10, 'EG00616', 2022, 10900, '20151001', '20151001' UNION
SELECT 10, 'EG00617', 56, 12400, '20150701', '20150701' UNION
SELECT 10, 'EG00617', 35, 6099, '20150801', '20150801';
```

Como verás:

- Los datos de tus dos tablas los voy a manejar en una sola (`TablaTest`) para que se más fácil de comprender.
- Entiendo que el acumulado debiera ser por `ID` y `PLACA`, si no fuera así no es complicado de ajustar esto.
- Agregué un ejemplo más de una `PLACA` ficticia, simplemente para evaluar que funcione adecuadamente

La consulta:

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, PLACA ORDER BY ID, PLACA, YEAR(FECHA2), MONTH(FECHA1)
    ), 
    ID,
    PLACA,
    SUM(GALONES) AS GALONES,
    SUM(MONTO) AS MONTO,
    MONTH(FECHA1) AS MES,
    YEAR(FECHA2) AS AÑO  
    FROM TablaTest
    WHERE MONTH(FECHA1) BETWEEN 6 AND 12 
             AND ID=10 
             AND YEAR(FECHA2)=2015
    GROUP BY MONTH(FECHA1),
             YEAR(FECHA2),
             ID,
             PLACA
)
SELECT  T1.ID,
        T1.PLACA,
        T1.GALONES,
        T1.MONTO,
        T1.MES,
        T1.AÑO,
        SUM(t2.MONTO*(CASE WHEN T2.rn>1 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END)) AS ACUMULADO
        FROM cte T1
        LEFT JOIN cte T2
            ON T1.rn >= T2.rn
            AND T1.ID = T2.ID
            AND T1.PLACA = T2.PLACA
        GROUP BY T1.rn,
                 T1.ID,
                 T1.PLACA,
                 T1.GALONES,
                 T1.MONTO,
                 T1.MES,
                 T1.AÑO;
```

La salida:

```
╔════╦═════════╦═════════╦═══════╦═════╦══════╦═══════════╗
║ ID ║ PLACA   ║ GALONES ║ MONTO ║ MES ║ AÑO  ║ ACUMULADO ║
╠════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════╬═════╬══════╬═══════════╣
║ 10 ║ EG00616 ║ 56      ║ 12400 ║ 7   ║ 2015 ║ 12400     ║
╠════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════╬═════╬══════╬═══════════╣
║ 10 ║ EG00616 ║ 35      ║ 6099  ║ 8   ║ 2015 ║ 6301      ║
╠════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════╬═════╬══════╬═══════════╣
║ 10 ║ EG00616 ║ 5556    ║ 8974  ║ 9   ║ 2015 ║ -2673     ║
╠════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════╬═════╬══════╬═══════════╣
║ 10 ║ EG00616 ║ 2022    ║ 10900 ║ 10  ║ 2015 ║ -13573    ║
╠════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════╬═════╬══════╬═══════════╣
║ 10 ║ EG00617 ║ 56      ║ 12400 ║ 7   ║ 2015 ║ 12400     ║
╠════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════╬═════╬══════╬═══════════╣
║ 10 ║ EG00617 ║ 35      ║ 6099  ║ 8   ║ 2015 ║ 6301      ║
╚════╩═════════╩═════════╩═══════╩═════╩══════╩═══════════╝
```

Ver [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4b760/2)

- En primer lugar creamos una [CTE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) con nuestra consulta principal y generando una columna adicional con el número de fila por `ID` y `PLACA` (`PARTITION BY`)
- Luego simplemente usamos la [CTE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) de forma recursiva para hacer lo que mencionaba más arriba.